# How to achieve this pattern with regex

Tags: jquery, regex

I'm implementing ***live validations*** with ***jquery*** and I'm taking the help of a ***regular expression*** to match my requirement.

***Requirement:***

Password must be **alphanumeric**(i.e, must contain atleast one alphabet and one integer) and may contain(i.e, optional) **special characters**.

***What I've tried:***

Below is the code I tried and it didn't worked.

```
jQuery("#bgpass").validate({
    expression: "if (VAL.match(/^(?=[A-Za-z0-9@%&#]$)(?=.*\d)(?=.*[A-Za-z]).*$/)) return true; else return false;",
    message: "Password must be alphanumeric and can contain some special characters"
  });
```

***Problem:***

Passwords without having atleast **one alphabet and one integer** are being allowed.

***Examples for which are being allowed:***

```
1234567 - Doesn't contain atleast one alphabet. 
amazing - Doesn't contain atleast one integer. 
am@zing - Doesn't contain atleast one integer. 
123$567 - Doesn't contain atleast one alphabet.
```

What I'm doing wrong!

***P.S:*** I'm very new to ***Regular Expressions***.

Comment: You forgot to add a `+` modifier in `(?=[A-Za-z0-9@%&#]$)`. Should work fine after that

Answer (score 1):

There is some issue with the regex that you have. You can modify it as

```
/^(?=.*\d)(?=.*[A-Za-z])/
```

[**Regex Demo**](https://regex101.com/r/2024kR/1)

---

- `^` Anchors the regex at the start of the string.
- `(?=.*\d)` This is a positive look ahead. It checks if the string contains a digit.
- `(?=.*[A-Za-z])` Another positive look ahead. This checks if the string contains anything followed by alphabet.

---

**What is wrong with `^(?=[A-Za-z0-9@%&#]$)(?=.*\d)(?=.*[A-Za-z]).*$/`?**

- `^(?=[A-Za-z0-9@%&#]$)` This positive look ahead means, match start of the string, `^`. Check if the start is followed by anything in the list then immediately match end of the string, `$`. Which is not a possible case. So the regex will not match any input string.

Answer (score 1):

```
^(?=[A-Za-z0-9@%&#]+$)(?=.*\d)(?=.*[A-Za-z]).*$

                   ^^
```

You missed a quantifier.Else its working fine.There is something wrong with your code.

See demo.

https://regex101.com/r/Jw8xty/1

Comment: I got a syntax error saying `SyntaxError: missing ) after condition` when I tried your code.

Comment: I've given it like this `expression: "if (VAL.match(/^(?=[A-Za-z0-9@%&#]+$)(?=.*\d)(?=.*[A-Za-z]).*$/) return true; else return false;"`

Comment: Sorry my bad!! I've missed an `)`. Rectified it but now ***amazing*** still being allowed but not ***1234567***. No errors.

Comment: Oops. Sorry. ***amazing*** is not allowed now but the random words like ***asdfgh*** are being allowed.

Comment: Yes. I'm testing one by one.

Comment: I get the same with @nu11p01n73R answer too!!

Comment: Both the regular expressions seems correct(atleast with the demos). Could be a problem with jquery i guess or may be i'm applying it wrong. Thanks for helping.

Comment: Well, this is interesting. Some random words are not being allowed and some being allowed!!

Comment: @Pavan in the regex link i provided there is a code generator as well.Can you try that code